# Convert String to Timestamp with milliseconds

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, sql-timestamp

I need to convert a string value to timestamp in Spark SQL **while retaining the milliseconds part**. The string value is :`'2018-05-15 14:12:44.185'`. I tried to `type-cast` it but it truncates the milliseconds part.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018-05-15 14:12:44.185', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'))
```

Can anyone please help so that the milliseconds part is also retained in the resulting value ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the unix timestamp is an integer measuring the number of seconds.  It doesn't have a fractional seconds component.

Comment: so is there any work around to this problem such that the milliseconds is retained in the target

Comment: . . I don't know.  I don't have a SparkSQL installation handy to test on.  One option is to convert to a date/time and then add the milliseconds afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [function `to_timestamp()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#to_timestamp) to convert the string to a timestamp, like:

```
select to_timestamp('2018-05-15 14:12:44.185', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
df.withColumn("eventTime1", unix_timestamp('2018-05-15 14:12:44.185', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").cast(TimestampType))
```